# Agora video call issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

While we are using Agora video call in flutter it is not working if the app is running in background. (Foreground working).

Any idea to get the thinks done while using Google FCM.

Answer (score 0):

Agora RTCEngine does not guaranty you that it will run in the background. We have to initialize the RTCEngine in service and start foreground service. The foreground service will keep the engine alive when the app goes to background. Agora doesn't have an example for this in flutter. You have to write the wrapper by yourself. A good place to start https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/Video-Call-with-Chat